# How to setup no-nonsense home network backup for Windows 7 laptops?

Tags: backup, windows-backup

I have two Windows 7 laptops on my WiFi network. Each has approx. 500GB of data (primarily photos, songs and Word/PDF files). I also have an old desktop computer (2GHz, 2GB RAM, 1.5TB drive, network card) running Windows XP Home.

I'd like to setup a fool-proof backup solution that:

1) creates a mirror image of all my files on each Win 7 laptop (one for each laptop with a browsable file tree structure mirroring the source drive),
2) every night, updates backup over WiFi by adding/removing any new files,
3) requires minimal maintenance, and
4) is free, or as free as possible, while meeting the criteria above

I have looked at a number of choices but am overwhelmed by the solutions offered by most how-to sites. I am not averse to formatting the desktop and loading a Linux build dedicated to backup management - but I'm looking for simplicity and ease of use in the solution, not bells and whistles that make day to day management a pain (e.g., don't need versioning).

Thanks.

Comment: I should've clarified, I'm looking for a free solution (or as free as possible).

Comment: Is it a requirement (for security or personal inclination or otherwise) that you store these yourself?  This sounds like a job for *Dropbox* to me if you want the least hassle, personally.

Comment: @Shinrai - partly personal inclination, partly security (I have a lot of tax and accounting docs related to my own business that I don't want hosted on the cloud). Secondly, I will have to purchase a paid Dropbox solution for the storage I need and I'd like to get a free solution if I can.

Comment: Gotcha - just felt like I should throw the obvious solution out there, a lot of people still overlook it. :) I'm not too familiar with the state of Linux based centralized backup these days myself, so I'm afraid I can't offer much more except to say that if I were in your spot I'd be asking this exact question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set-and-forget Windows backup software with NAS-support?](http://superuser.com/questions/25616/set-and-forget-windows-backup-software-with-nas-support)

Answer (score 3):

By far your easiest option will be [Windows Home Server](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=windows%20home%20server&safe=active&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=4576823068592733085&sa=X&ei=svquTseUOMSGsALs9o3eDg&ved=0CGcQ8wIwAw).  It's not free, but you won't do any better for Windows.

After that, there are a number of [free](http://www.freenas.org/) [linux-based](http://www.openfiler.com/) [NAS](http://www.amahi.org/) packages, and some of them have good support for setting backups. But none of them approach the level of convenience at this time that Microsoft's own offering brings.

Comment: I considered WHS, however looking for a free solution...I suppose that puts me squarely into Linux territory given my requirements. I have added a comment to clarify my question.

Comment: @Zee: You need to add that as an edit to your question.  WHS will also smoke any solution out there, bar none.